# Open a program in linux using a web interface

Tags: linux, apache, cgi

Is there any way to open a program such as a webbrowser on a linux machine using a webinterface? I tried a simple cgi script

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "Content-type: text/html"
midori
exit 0
```

But I'm getting a response on the page the browser can't open an interface...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To avoid permissions problem make sure that the same user runs X server and web server.

You have to set two variables XAUTHORITY and DISPLAY. Try with this script:

```
#!/bin/bash
export XAUTHORITY=/home/<username>/.Xauthority
export DISPLAY=':0'
midori &
```

replace < username> with the username of the user who owns the X server process